# Usage of setRange() in Google Apps Script Protection Class

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to alter the dimensions of a protected range but keep getting:
"Cannot find method setRange(string)"

The Google Developers site doesn't give any examples.
See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setrangerange

How should I be using setRange() in the code below?

```
 function editIt() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
     if (protection.getRangeName() == 'Test') {
      var range = 'A7:A28';
      protection.setRange(range);
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setRange()` takes a range object, not just a string with range dimesions. So you have to get a range object using [`sheet.getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)). Your code would be this

```
function editIt() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // additional line to get sheet
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
     if (protection.getRangeName() == 'Test') {
     var range = sheet.getRange('A7:A28'); // edited line
      protection.setRange(range);
      }
     }
    }
```